# Can't connect to Mongo Cloud mongodb Database in Golang on Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, go, ubuntu

I have this Go Code to connect to my Mongo Cloud Database:

```
func connectToDataBase() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 20*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI(dbURL))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error connecting to Database: ", err.Error())
    }
    DB = client.Database("storyfactory")
}
```

I already ran this code on a Windows machine, and it worked. Now I tried to run it on ubuntu, and I get following error:

```
2019/04/13 00:20:37 Error connecting to Database: error parsing uri (mongodb+srv://User:Password@cluster0-gpxjk.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true): lookup cluster0-gpxjk.gcp.mongodb.net on 127.0.0.53:53: cannot unmarshal DNS message
exit status 1
```

I don't know, why it worked on windows, and now it doesn't on ubuntu.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Questions: 1) Are you using Golang version 1.11 ? 2) Are you using Docker for the Ubuntu ? Or the Windows and the Ubuntu are completely different machine ?

Answer (score 19):

> cannot unmarshal DNS message

This is not quite related to MongoDB Go driver.

There is a patch in Go version 1.11.x [#10622 net: target domain names in SRV records should not be compressed](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10622) that tighten the way SRV records are read to follow RFC-2782.

If an authoritative DNS server (non-compliantly) sends an SRV records using domain name compression, the `net.lookupSRV()` will throw an error with `cannot unmarshal DNS message` ([net/lookup_unix.go#L130](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.11/src/net/lookup_unix.go#L130)). For example, the embedded Docker DNS maybe doing the server name compression.

The workarounds for Go v1.11 are:

- Use the non-SRV MongoDB URI
- Update the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` by replacing the `nameserver` to use a compliant and/or public DNS server i.e. `1.1.1.1` or `8.8.8.8`

See also [GODRIVER-829](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/GODRIVER-829)

Comment: actually updating the resolv.conf worked fine. thank you

Comment: @OWADVL: beware that [changes to resolv.conf do not persist reboots](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174349/what-overwrites-etc-resolv-conf-on-every-boot), and it's [non-trivial to fix that](https://superuser.com/questions/677343/how-to-make-name-server-address-permanent-in-etc-resolv-conf).

Answer (score 6):

The work around is to use non SRV connection string. Go to Mongo Atlas to get your connection string as per normal.

Driver select Java, version 3.4 or later

You should now see you connection string. Works with go1.13.8.

Comment: Thanks, this worked out for me, and persists across reboots.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174349/what-overwrites-etc-resolv-conf-on-every-boot)
suggests installing resolvconf (for Ubuntu `apt install resolvconf`), add the line `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`, then run `sudo resolvconf -u` and to be sure `service resolvconf restart`.
To verify run `systemd-resolve --status`.

You should see on the first line your DNS server like here:

```
         DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8
          DNS Domain: sa-east-1.compute.internal
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
```