# MongoDB: DNS issue of resolv.conf connecting to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, dns, ubuntu-18.04

I want to export some data from MongoDB Atlas.

If I execute the command below, It tries connect `localhost` and export the data.

```
mongoexport --uri="mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@name-of-project-x2lpw.mongodb.net/test" --collection users --out /tmp/testusers.json
```

**Note:** If you run this command from Windows CMD, [it works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60214558/3710490)

After researching the problem and with the help of a user, everything seems to point to a DNS problem and to the related `resolv.conf` file.

Below the original `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search name.com
```

At the beginning that resulted into a connection failure as shown below:

[image: wrong]

But if I would change that address into the following public available address according to what advised on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55660134/cant-connect-to-mongo-cloud-mongodb-database-in-golang-on-ubuntu) to `1.1.1.1` the connection is successful, see below:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 1.1.1.1
options edns0
search name.com
```

Which resulted into a connection success as shown below:

[image: correct]

**HOWEVER** the problem is that instead of explicitly connecting to the name of the `MongoDB` cluster, it will connect to the `localhost`, which is very strange as I successfully exported the files I was looking for from the real connection.
**Which means** that the machine was correctly connecting to the database but via `localhost`.

Everything seems to lead, also according to [this source](https://datawookie.netlify.com/blog/2018/10/dns-on-ubuntu-18.04/) and also [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174349/what-overwrites-etc-resolv-conf-on-every-boot) to a DNS problem while connecting to `MongoDB` via terminal to export collections.
Now from this last post it not advisable to manually change this address for several reasons, therefore right after successfully exporting the data using `DNS 1.1.1.1` I changed it back to its original `DNS 127.0.0.53`.
However I don't think this should be a proper behavior as every time I need to export data I will have to continuously and manually change this address.

What could be the reason for this strange behavior? And therefore what could be a long term solution without manually switching between DNS addresses?

Thanks for pointing to the right direction for solving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you all ready have the answer in the links you mentioned. I will [summarize this:](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174349/what-overwrites-etc-resolv-conf-on-every-boot)

Install resolvconf (for Ubuntu `apt install resolvconf`), add the line `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`, then run `sudo resolvconf -u` and to be sure `service resolvconf restart`.
To verify run `systemd-resolve --status`.

You should see on the first line your DNS server like here:

```
         DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8
          DNS Domain: sa-east-1.compute.internal
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
```

This solution persists between reboots.