# mongodb dump fails with cannot unmarshal DNS message

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I am using a mongo db server version MongoDB shell version v4.0.16 installed on a EC2 instance.

I am able to get into the instance using mongo command

```
mongo mongodb+srv://dxxxxxxx:xxxxxx[][]@cluster0-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net 
MongoDB shell version v4.0.16
connecting to: mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-02-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-00-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017/?authSource=admin&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&ssl=true
2020-03-05T09:02:45.265+0000 I NETWORK  [js] Starting new replica set monitor for Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-02-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-00-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017
2020-03-05T09:02:45.604+0000 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Successfully connected to cluster0-shard-00-00-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017 (1 connections now open to cluster0-shard-00-00-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017 with a 5 second timeout)
2020-03-05T09:02:45.607+0000 I NETWORK  [js] Successfully connected to cluster0-shard-00-01-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017 (1 connections now open to cluster0-shard-00-01-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017 with a 5 second timeout)
2020-03-05T09:02:45.707+0000 I NETWORK  [js] changing hosts to Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 from Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017
2020-03-05T09:02:46.010+0000 I NETWORK  [js] Successfully connected to cluster0-shard-00-00-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 (1 connections now open to cluster0-shard-00-00-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 with a 5 second timeout)
2020-03-05T09:02:46.028+0000 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Successfully connected to cluster0-shard-00-01-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 (1 connections now open to cluster0-shard-00-01-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 with a 5 second timeout)
2020-03-05T09:02:46.439+0000 I NETWORK  [js] Successfully connected to cluster0-shard-00-02-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 (1 connections now open to cluster0-shard-00-02-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 with a 5 second timeout)
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("1c7432d5-e09c-45f8-8d84-d47e4f572cbf") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.3
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
Error while trying to show server startup warnings: user is not allowed to do action [getLog] on [admin.]
MongoDB Enterprise Cluster0-shard-0:PRIMARY>
```

I am trying to connect to a mongo db Atlas to get the database using mongodump

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb+srv://dxxxxxxx:xxxxxx[][]@cluster0-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net/xxxxxxxxxx"
```

I am facing issues with

```
error parsing command line options: error parsing uri (mongodb+srv://dxxxxxxx:xxxxxx[]@cluster0-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net/xxxxxxxxxx): lookup cluster0-vxcen.gcp.mongodb.net on 127.0.0.53:53: cannot unmarshal DNS message
```

Comment: What is your OS? Also try to login with `mongo --uri="URI HERE"`, should give same error. Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60214558/3710490) helps you

Answer (score 69):

This is just a case of incompatible DNS server.

Locate `/etc/resolv.conf` file and replace the nameserver with `8.8.8.8`, and everything should work just fine. If that does not work , try `1.1.1.1`.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 this is `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: This was helpful to me - thank you.  On MacOS you can set this by going to System Preferences --> Network --> Advanced then click on the DNS button.  Add both 8.8.8.8 and 1.1.1.1 and it should work.

Comment: This fixed my problem while trying to connect using the Go driver. I'm curious as to what this change actually did though. Are there security implications that I should be aware of?

Comment: This is so helpful! I was going nuts trying to solve this until I found this answer!

Answer (score 6):

This issue is simmilar to the one reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55660134/cant-connect-to-mongo-cloud-mongodb-database-in-golang-on-ubuntu).
The fix for changing resolv.conf as above seems not to persist reboots.
The workaround proposed in the link above is either to use non srv url, or, a simpler way that and as far as I have seen survives reboots as well, is to remove the symlink `/etc/resolve.conf` and replace it with a **static** file containing the required DNS server.

Another option, found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174349/what-overwrites-etc-resolv-conf-on-every-boot)
Suggests installing resolvconf (for Ubuntu `apt install resolvconf`), add the line `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`, then run `sudo resolvconf -u` and to be sure `service resolvconf restart`.
To verify run `systemd-resolve --status`.

You should see on the first line your DNS server like here:

```
         DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8
          DNS Domain: sa-east-1.compute.internal
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
```

Answer (score 3):

Two solutions that worked for me:

1. Add nameserver with value `8.8.8.8` or `1.1.1.1` additionally to existing ones in `/etc/resolve.conf` file
2. Use connection string in format `mongodb://{db}:{pass}@hostname1.mongodb.net,hostname2.mongodb.net,hostname3.mongodb.net/admin?authSource=admin&replicaSet={replicaSet}&readPreference=primary&ssl=true` instead of `mongodb+srv://` format

To get the formatted connection string, you can use `db.getMongo()` command on your cluster

Answer (score 1):

In some causes, for example in environment where you can't change resolver you can use old style URL:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://<username>:<password>@<cluster>...
```

After change URL generated by cloud.mongodb.com Atlas
in section Cluster -> Connect -> Choose a connection method -> Python - 3.4 or later

It finally started working.

My setup:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Python 2.7.17 / 2.7.12
- Pymongo 3.11.1
- Google Cloud SDK 319.0.0

Comment: this worked for me also in CLI:  mongodump "<string generated by cloud.mongodb.com>" but this is not the best solution because this uri is obsolete

Answer (score 0):

In my case, only MongoDB connections went wrong with my DNS server.
However, it worked with Google DNS 8.8.8.8, as suggested above.
The solution for me was to decrease the UDP max packet size (same as Google DNS)

```
cat /etc/bind/named.conf.options
options {
    #...
    listen-on { 127.0.0.1; };
    allow-recursion { 127.0.0.1; ::1; };
    edns-udp-size 512;
    max-udp-size 512;
};
```