# MongoDB Collection export error Path collision at tokens

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am trying to export my collections from Atlas to my Local MongoDB with MongoDB Compass tool. The issue is I can export some collections but my user collection returning error.

Error is: Path collision at tokens.0BUo4-zWowM9ldTIUbs57Q remaining portion 0BUo4-zWowM9ldTIUbs57Q

Any help appreciated, thanks.

MongoDB Compass version is 1.28.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By some search, I saw some other people facing similar problem. So it may be caused by some bug on MongoDB Compass version is 1.28.1. Workaround solution was using command line interface like below.

```
mongodump --uri="<connection-string>" --out /path/to/export
```

Comment: "cannot unmarshal DNS message"

Comment: Locate /etc/resolv.conf file and replace the nameserver with 8.8.8.8, and everything should work just fine. If that does not work , try 1.1.1.1.  from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60560041/14066260

Answer (score 5):

This error occurs because there are two different types. Probably you have your token set as an object, or as an empty string.

The solution to use `Mongo Compass` is manually unchecking the "Root level field" that marks as a string. Check the following example:

The error occurs because the field "Fotos_da_Ocorrência" can be an empty string `""` or and object `{bucketName: "", comment: "", elementId: ""}`.

When i uncheck the `Root Level Field` it exports normally.
[image: Fields Example]

[image: Exported]

Answer (score 3):

Gustavo is correct about the two types issue, but the solution depends on your use case and the data you're interested in.

In my case I have documents with a config field that can be either an object or null:

`{ config: null }`

`{ config: { token: "abc123", date: "2023-05-24T08:25:19" }}`

When I export in Compass and it asks me to select fields, I get 3 options:

- config
- config.token
- config.date

By having the root field and the sub-fields selected, there is an overlap in the fields that are exported, hence the path collision issue. To resolve this, you can either deselect `config` or only select `config`.

If you deselect `config` (i.e. just select the sub-fields), then the output documents will only contain the `config` field if there is data for the sub-fields. In any documents where `config` is null, the `config` field is omitted.

If you only select `config` (i.e. deselect the sub-fields) then the output will contain the `config` field regardless of whether it is null or an object. It will still be omitted if it is undefined.